# php to open, read, transfer to/from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, cron, text-files

I've read some posts where a php file opens and writes the info to a database. But it has a delimeter such as `|` or `,` or `.`.

However, I have a txt file that deals with numbers and the delimter is a space between numbers.

For example user 1 with userlevel of site 12 and admin status of 12:

```
977970 12 12
```

Another example of multiple users:

```
977970 password 12 12
100490 password 3  12
```

Each new line is a new user with their indiviual details.

And the second half to this, is that it needs to update the text file with new users. I'm sure the update will need a cron job running.

Comment: What's the question?  Presumably you're trying to implement this; are you encountering some problem?

Comment: Where does MySQL come in? You only told us about parsing text files and updating text files. Do you need to import the text file into a MySQL table and it back into a text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood the problem right. You are trying to read from a file and store it into a database where your records are **delimited by space** & I haven't checked the code but it should work or at least give you an idea

```
<?php
    $data = Array();
    $handle = @fopen("/Your/File.txt", "r");  
    if ($handle) {
       while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
          $data[]= $line;                    // read each line and store in array
       }
       if (!feof($handle)) {
           echo "Error";
       }
       fclose($handle);
       getDelimitedVals($data);
   }
```

your function to separate the record

```
   function getDelimitedVals($data) {
       if(empty($data)) {
           return false;
       }
       foreach($data as $line) {
           $dbData[] = explode(" ", $line);     // this will separate the uname, pwd, id and store in new arry
       }

       return dbData;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part, there are quite a number of ways to parse a 'something' delimited file, but here's a pretty simple solution:

```
$contents = file('filename/goes/here');

foreach($contents AS $line) {
    $values = explode(' ', $line);
    /**
     *  $values = array(
     *      '977970',
     *      'password',
     *      '12',
     *      '12'
     *  )
     */
}
```

Comment: now, with the file itself, should I use the absolute path or do I need to place it in the root directory of the web server.